# Show that resolvent of $L:=-\partial_v (\partial_v +v)$ is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, compact-operators

In the following, I am referring to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.02173.pdf), p. 9.

Consider the operator $L:=-\partial_v (\partial_v + v)$ which is self-adjoint on
$$
\mathcal{M}:=\mu L^2(\mu\, dv)=\{g = \mu f: f\in L^2(\mu\, dv)\}
$$
(with norm $\Vert g\Vert_\mathcal{M}=\Vert g/\mu\Vert_{L^2(\mu\, dv)}=\int\vert g\vert^2\mu^{-1}\, dv$ and inner product $\langle f,g\rangle_\mathcal{M}=\int fg\mu^{-1}\, dv$ where $\mu(v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-v^2/2}$ and $\mu\, dv=\mu(v)\, dv$).

It is said without proof that **$L$ has **compact resolvent**.**

I would like to verify this claim. Unfortunately, I did not manage to do so; in fact, I do not even know how to determine the resolvent itself...

Comment: The operator $L$ looks very similar to the Sturm-Liouville operator defining the Hermite polynomials https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermiteDifferentialEquation.html You may be able to explicitly find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $L$ and show that the eigenvalues go to infinity, which should go a long way to showing the resolvant is compact.

Comment: @whpowell96: great advice. Hermite ODE reads $-\partial_v^2 + 2v\partial_v - \lambda$. The present one is $-\partial_v^2-v\partial_v -1$. There is no sign alternation here. I wonder whether this is a substantial difference or if there is a way to reconduct this ODE to the Hermite one.

Comment: @selector: The operator I see in the linked paper is different. You wrote $L:=-\partial_v (\partial_v + v)$. In the paper I see a $-(\partial_v + v)\partial_v $. Which one is correct? Note that this is important, as $[\partial_v, v]\ne 0$.

Comment: Even if there is no way to reduce to a Hermite (The gaussian measure makes me suspicious that there is), then one can use the same techniques to solve this eigenvalue problem. At the very least, showing this is a Sturm Liouville problem is sufficient to show that $L$ has a minimum positive eigenvalue, for instance

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro In line (14), the operator is as you say. But in the paragraph before line (14), the operator is as I wrote. As far as I understood, they claim that the operator as I defined it has compact resolvent.

Comment: @whpowell96 I know the following statement: If $L$ is self-adjoint and has a compact resolvent, then its spectrum is real, discrete and can be written as a sequence tending to $+\infty$ in absolute value.  - So you seem to suggest to use this (by contradiction).

Comment: This operator is regular Sturm-Liouville. These operators always have compact resolvent on $L^2([a, b])$. Here you have a Gaussian measure on $\mathbb R$ but I am sure that the proof carries over to this case. I found this note online: https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4400/v21/sturml.pdf

Comment: The proof at the end of this note may be helpful as well https://projecteuclid.org/journals/methods-and-applications-of-analysis/volume-16/issue-3/Completeness-of-Eigenfunctions-of-Sturm-Liouville-Problems-with-Transmission-Conditions/maa/1273002794.pdf

Comment: This link I posted is about nonstandard boundary  conditions but the proof is still the same I think